# Excecute iwconfig from a java application

Tags: java, linux, shell

Is it possible to execute iwconfig (or any other shell based program) from a java application and then parse the output somehow?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by using the [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) API.

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new API. It's new since 1.5 and I'd never seen it before. Old school was `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: That's right. Check out the inimitable Roedy Green for a nice exegesis of the API. http://mindprod.com/jgloss/exec.html#PROCESSBUILDER