# Wireless API for Linux in C or Java

Tags: java, c, linux, wireless

my team and I are working in a project based on the drone Parrot API. 
We are trying to find an api to write a small program which can scan the wireless network and selects the drone ESSID. Our main language is C but Java is also appreciated.

I tried to look if exist any API for the iwlist/iwconfig command but i did not find anything.
Can someone help me plz? Any example (code sample) will also be appreciated.

Gracias

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With newer kernels the framework for managing wireless cards is called **nl80211**.  It's netlink based, so you can use **libnl** to issue commands and parse answers.  More information:

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/nl80211

Currently **iw** is the command line utility that utilizes nl80211, so you can list available hardware, scan, etc:

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw

Its source code is easy to study and reuse in your own project, just check out their git repo.

Comment: The above links are not working... Can anyone please provide a link from where I can get those information.

Answer (score 1):

No API but you can try: [Excecute iwconfig from a java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875593/excecute-iwconfig-from-a-java-application)

You can also try http://kosmosisland.com/island/david/kosmos-island-wireless.php . They have a Java Applet (with source) that monitors the Wireless Link. You can see how they did it.

Gustavo