# error: 'WlanScan' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, scope, wlanapi

I have been playing around with wlanapi in windows. I did not have any problem compiling or running until I tried using the function [WlanScan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706783(v=vs.85).aspx). Then I was unable to compile due to "WlanScan" not being declared in the scope. I wrote a really short program illustrating this using two functions: [WlanOpenHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706759(v=vs.85).aspx) that works and [WlanScan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706783(v=vs.85).aspx) which doesn't.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wlanapi.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hClient;
    WlanOpenHandle(2, 0, 0, &hClient);

    WlanScan(hClient, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Compiling that single file like this:

```
g++ main.cpp -lwlanapi
```

Results in this error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:30: error: 'WlanScan' was not declared in this scope
  WlanScan(hClient, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                              ^
```

What could be the cause of this? I've been able to use a handful of functions from the wlanapi. I am on Windows 7 compiling with minGW.

**EDIT:**
In accordance to what u/ IInspectable said, I changed the command used to compile to:

```
g++ -D_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 main.cpp -lwlanapi
```

And it worked!

Comment: Your `main` function needs to return an integer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews True, but that's for the next question -- don't get ahead of yourself. :)

Comment: @FKunecke What do you mean? This is c++, the compiler takes care of that

Comment: You declared the `main()` function as returning an `int`.  Where does you code satisfy the declaration?  Ideally, you should specify the return value to the operating system rather than relying on compilers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That may be true. But it is irrelevant to my question.

Comment: @EFTH I updated my answer; I'm curious though -- try just adding `#pragma comment(lib, "wlanapi.lib")` to your current code and see what happens.

Comment: @FKunecke Thank you for the help. But adding that line did not help.

Comment: @EFTH did it give you the same error?  I'm not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @FKunecke Yeah, same error. I've looked around in my machine and been able to find two wlanapi.h files so far, both of which declare the function

Comment: @ThomasMatthews : it should, but doesn't need to (implicit `return 0`)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/204483/1889329)

Comment: Make sure the preprocessor symbol `_WIN32_WINNT` is set to `_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP` (or higher, e.g. `_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA`, `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7`). The symbol must be defined prior to including the `<wlanapi.h>` header file. It's recommended to pass it on the compiler's command line.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you! That worked. I updated the question to include this solution. If you put this in a real answer I can mark this question done and dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone else has had this problem before:

[How To Compile C++ Code that has a 'wlanapi.h' and 'windows.h' dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621013/how-to-compile-c-code-that-has-a-wlanapi-h-and-windows-h-dependency)

The recommended solution is to just put it into Visual Studio and compile it using that; MinGW probably isn't able to find the library.

---

Using VS2010 I created a VC++ console application (with a precompiled header), and I was able to get the following to compile without any errors:

```
// wlanapi_Test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hClient;
    WlanOpenHandle(2, 0, 0, &hClient);

    WlanScan(hClient, 0, 0, 0, 0);

}
```

And here's my precompiled header:

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>



// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here


#include <windows.h>
#include <wlanapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wlanapi.lib")
```

Comment: The magic happens inside `"targetver.h"`. If you don't provide this file (which Visual Studio generated for you automatically), it does nothing to help answer the question. In addition, the question states a **compiler** error (vs. a **linker** error), so this has nothing to do with not finding a library.