# Wireless API for Linux in C\C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, wireless, signal-strength

I'm trying to find a proper way how to reuse existing implementations of wifi tools(iw) in own code(c\c++). I need to get information about available AccessPoints in range(signal strength, mac addr., etc). I found couple example codes(WEXT and others) that uses ioctl approach, but it makes passive scans(and i get new information only once in two minutes in my network)[**UPDATE1**: *Thanks to @fluter, i know that WEXT can do active scanning, too*.]. I found that iw makes an active scan and that is what i need. So my question:

> Is there a way to use iw code in my own app without parsing its source code in chunks, or, maybe, there is an Wireless API for such purpose?
>
> (**UPDATE1**: with basic code examples to start with.)

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102186/wireless-api-for-linux-in-c-or-java/36771973#36771973)

**UPDATE2**: I have reviewed my task and found that AP information is not enough for me, i need to capture clients data, too. That leads me to wifi packet sniffing and the best tool i have found to do that is Horst. So, i'm trying to reuse its code in my app, now.

Comment: If iw does what you need why not just invoke it?

Comment: do you mean to call it from my code? I don't know if it's a good idea, but i am ready to hear arguments for it. And if there is an option to accomplish my task in a clean way i prefer to search for that.

Comment: yes. Could you elaborate a bit more on the desired result? For instance what kind of data structure to store it, or just plain text to be parsed later etc.

Comment: basic data that i need is mac, essid, signal_strength and noise, channel, last_seen. i suppose to temporary store it in a structure(code) for processing purposes, like it does in WEXT and any other program. Maybe, i'll be storing this data with processed one in a file, but it's not the main goal.

Answer (score 2):

You might wish to start with [cfg80211](http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/developers/Documentation/cfg80211/).

cfg80211 replaces [Wireless-Extensions](http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/developers/Documentation/Wireless-Extensions) and it is suggested that :

> All new Linux wireless drivers should be written targeting either cfg80211 for fullmac devices or mac80211 for softmac devices.

Also, it is written:

> Instead of writing wext ioctls you now write cfg80211 operation
>   callbacks and fill in the wiphy struct to indicate to cfg80211 its
>   device capabilities.

To start with active scanning start [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/net/cfg80211.h#L1436)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me into right direction. I'll check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wext api provided by kernel, basically, call `ioctl` with `SIOCSIWSCAN`, and get the scanned result with `SIOCGIWSCAN`.
You can set to scan all by using flag `IW_SCAN_ALL_ESSID`, and choose scan type with flag `IW_SCAN_TYPE_ACTIVE` or `IW_SCAN_TYPE_PASSIVE`.

Comment: good one, i missed that flag. Thank you!

Comment: placed this flag for request and nothing changed - only passive scanning. am i missing something?

Comment: @diabolusss post your code to check.

Comment: actually i am wrong, sorry. i checked again this flags using another code and it worked!

Comment: @diabolusss ok, glad to know it's working.